# How to understand `JavaScript static methods are also not callable when the class is instantiated`

Tags: javascript, class, static

I read it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods).
The original is:

> The `static` keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods are called without instantiating their class and are also not callable when the class is instantiated.

I thought `static` in js is similar to `static` in java but the sentence in question confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar. However, Java allows calling static methods on the instance:

```
p1.distance(p1, p2);
```

which does the same thing as

```
Point.distance(p1, p2);
```

The first one is not allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks. I now understand. The sentence means *Static methods cannot be used as instance methods*.

Comment: While it is allowed in Java, it is bad practice, can be confusing, and the compiler will issue a warning.

Comment: @Thilo: Yep. Always baffled me why that was even allowed, as it makes no sense whatsoever.