# Why does jQuery store some of it's methods on it's prototype and others directly on itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon inspecting the jQuery object I noticed that jQuery puts some of it's methods on the actual jQuery instance itself & others on the jQuery objects prototype object. Does anyone know why jQuery might do this (performance ...etc)?

```
console.dir(jQuery.prototype)
------------------
▼ Object
add: function(){....}
addBack: function(){...}
addClass: function(){...}
after: function(){....}
.....more methods

console.dir(jQuery)
----------------------
▼ Object
Animation: function(){...}
Callbacks: function(){....}
Deferred: function(){.....}
Event: function(){....}
Tween: function(){.......}
```

Comment: That's the nature of the API. Consider `$.ajax()` and `$.each()` versus `$(".foo").hide()` etc. There are simply two different kinds of methods: some for jQuery objects, and some that are essentially "global".

Comment: Note that the `jQuery` methods you listed in your example are all constructors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand \`JavaScript static methods are also not callable when the class is instantiated\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831113/how-to-understand-javascript-static-methods-are-also-not-callable-when-the-clas)